# Module not found, Can't resolve error in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

Everything works fine until I add this line

```
@Output() featureSelected = new EventEmitter();
```

Error I get is ./node_modules/saucelabs/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/SauceLabs' in 'C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\udemy\node_modules\saucelabs'

I am using Angular version 7.3.10 and node version 12.18.2

Comment: Can you please update your question/post with your `import...` statements?

Comment: Hey, sorry I should have done that.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't import EventEmitter from protractor. Please import it from @angular/core

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: @Intro Don't IDEs have warning for not imported classes?